# Reference a row from another Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have 2 DataFrames:

DataFrame 1

```
A  B
a  1
b  2
c  3
d  4
```

DataFrame2:

```
C D
a c 
b a
a b
```

The goal is to add a column to DataFrame 2 ('E').

```
C D E
a c (1-3=-2)
b a (2-1=1)
a b (1-2=-1)
```

If this were excel, a formula could be something similar to "=vlookup(A1,DataFrame1,2)-vlookup(B1,DataFrame1,2)". Any idea what this formula looks like in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Pandas Series can be thought of as a mapping from its index to its values.
Here, we wish to use the first DataFrame, `df1` as a mapping from column `A` to column `B`. So the natural thing to do is to convert `df1` into a Series:

```
s = df1.set_index('A')['B']
# A
# a    0
# b    1
# c    2
# d    3
# Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Now we can use the [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method to "lookup" values in a Series based on `s`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcd'), 'B':[1,2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':list('aba'), 'D':list('cab')})
s = df1.set_index('A')['B']
df2['E'] = df2['C'].map(s) - df2['D'].map(s)

print(df2)
```

yields

```
   C  D  E
0  a  c -2
1  b  a  1
2  a  b -1
```

Comment: Converting to Series is a nice trick that I didn't though of! Well done!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
#set column A as index, so you can index it
df1 = df1.set_index('A')

df2['E'] = df1.loc[df2.C, 'B'].values - df1.loc[df2.D, 'B'].values
```

And the result is:

```
   C  D  E
0  a  c -2
1  b  a  1
2  a  b -1
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
*Using `replace` and `eval` with `assign`*

```
df2.assign(E=df2.replace(df1.A.values, df1.B).eval('C - D'))

   C  D  E
0  a  c -2
1  b  a  1
2  a  b -1
```

---

I like this answer for it's succinctness.

- I use `replace` with two iterables, nameley `df1.A` that specifies what to replace and `df1.B` that specifies what to replace with.
- I use `eval` to elegantly perform the differencing of the new found `C` less `D`.
- I use `assign` to create a copy of `df2` with a new column named `E` that has the values from the steps above.

---

I could have used a dictionary instead `dict(zip(df1.A, df1.B))`

```
df2.assign(E=df2.replace(dict(zip(df1.A, df1.B))).eval('C - D'))

   C  D  E
0  a  c -2
1  b  a  1
2  a  b -1
```

---

**PROJECT**/*kill*
*`numpy` + `pd.factorize`*

```
base = df1.A.values
vals = df1.B.values
refs = df2.values.ravel()

f, u = pd.factorize(np.append(base, refs))
look = vals[f[base.size:]]
df2.assign(E=look[::2] - look[1::2])

   C  D  E
0  a  c -2
1  b  a  1
2  a  b -1
```

---

**Timing**
Among the pure `pandas` @unutbu's answer is the clear winner.  While my overly verbose `numpy` solution only improves by about 40ish%

Let's use these functions for the `numpy` versions.  Note `using_F_order` is @unutbu's contribution.

```
def using_numpy(df1, df2):
    base = df1.A.values
    vals = df1.B.values
    refs = df2.values.ravel()
    f, u = pd.factorize(np.append(base, refs))
    look = vals[f[base.size:]]
    return df2.assign(E=look[::2] - look[1::2])

def using_F_order(df1, df2):
    base = df1.A.values
    vals = df1.B.values
    refs = df2.values.ravel(order='F')
    f, u = pd.factorize(np.append(base, refs))
    look = vals[f[base.size:]].reshape(-1, 2, order='F')
    return df2.assign(E=look[:, 0]-look[:, 1])
```

*small data*

```
%timeit df2.assign(E=df2.replace(df1.A.values, df1.B).eval('C - D'))
%timeit df2.assign(E=df2.replace(dict(zip(df1.A, df1.B))).eval('C - D'))
%timeit df2.assign(E=(lambda s: df2['C'].map(s) - df2['D'].map(s))(df1.set_index('A')['B']))
%timeit using_numpy(df1, df2)
%timeit using_F_order(df1, df2)

100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 436 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 424 µs per loop
```

*large data*

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

upper = np.array(list(ascii_uppercase))
lower = np.array(list(ascii_lowercase))

ch = np.core.defchararray.add(upper[:, None], lower).ravel()

np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 100000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=ch, B=np.arange(ch.size)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(C=np.random.choice(ch, n), D=np.random.choice(ch, n)))

%timeit df2.assign(E=df2.replace(df1.A.values, df1.B).eval('C - D'))
%timeit df2.assign(E=df2.replace(dict(zip(df1.A, df1.B))).eval('C - D'))
%timeit df2.assign(E=(lambda s: df2['C'].map(s) - df2['D'].map(s))(df1.set_index('A')['B']))
%timeit using_numpy(df1, df2)
%timeit using_F_order(df1, df2)

1 loop, best of 3: 11.1 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 10.6 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.11 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice work on the timings. Would you mind timing [`using_F_order(df1, df2)`](http://ideone.com/TBknNI) as well? I'm seeing about 20% improvement for the numpy version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple way to achieve this:

```
newdf = df2.replace(['a','b','c','d'],[1,2,3,4])
df2['E'] = newdf['C'] - newdf['D']
df2
```

I hope this helps !